# Hardware to create a IVR and SMS system

Tags: sms, sip, voip, ivr

I developed a IVR and sms system using twilio.com. I have used it's api to develop the system. But now I want to have my own setup which does the same features. I did some home work and read things about VOIP and SIP. All those talks about internet calls. But this is something that I need to call a cell phone or land line and expect calls from those phones. Is this possible without using any hardware and also not relying on services like Twilio.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you want to do? If you want to develop IVR apps then you need some sort of server to be able to do that for you, like you did with Twilio. If you want to be able to have it at your *own* server then you can use Restcomm which is a similar solution to Twilio, with compatible APIs, but it's open source and you can run it anywhere you want, like your own linux/mac box, using Docker. For more info on that please check http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-quick-start-guide/

Comment: @atsakiridis, thanks for you reply. Yes It IVR apps. I should be able to make calls to mobile and land phones on a schedule basis. Lets say I have setup the Restcomm. But how does it make calls to phones. Do I need buy any subscription from some other Vendor?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Asterisk or Freeswitch project in AWS or Digital Ocean. Asterisk/Freeswitch offer IVR services, take a look at this [guide](http://gonzalogascameza.tumblr.com/post/139650313489/freeswitch-integration-with-twilio) and setup via Twilio documentation:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/sample-configuration#freeswitch

For PSTN integration, you can use Twilio or any other SIP trunk provider.
This will be the flow:

```
Cellphone > PSTN > Twilio/SIP Trunk > PBX -> IVR
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Even if I have the server setup in AWS or Digital Ocean, I need to have a SIP Trunk Vendor?. Lets say my application (Made from Asterisk/freeswitch) makes a call to a land/mobile phone, you mean to say I should be using a sip trunk vendor where I pay for the phone calls?

Comment: That is correct, when you call PSTN numbers (land/mobile) you need a Service Provider which will terminate the calls. A production grade solution requires a SP, for prototypes some people still use Google Voice.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own setup by having FreeSWITCH or Asterisk. these are the soft switch. you can generate your own logic for ivr. You can control the switch as per your guidance.

I suggest you to go with FreeSWITCH.

Comment: If you want i can help you as well guide you about freeswitch or asterisk.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Definitely i will get your help from you to setup this. But i am not clear enough on this concept. Let's say we setup the FreeSwtich on a server. Now How does this makes calls to land phone or mobile Phone? Do I need to buy services from other vendors. Let's say i want to make a call from application, I believe there is cost for this. To who I should pay this pls.

Comment: This is very simple, when you call from your cellphone or landline to a VoIP system, you need a Provider that performs this conversion. PSTN > IP World. Use Twilio, is very simple to setup. Of course you need to pay, there are free vendors, but a Twilio phone number is not expensive. Basically you buy a number from Twilio (Example: 14081112222, and in Twilio Portal you point it to your VoIP system) when you call this number Twilio will take care of handling the call and send it to your IPPBX, you need to configure both sides. Check Twilio IP PBX integration guides.

Comment: You have buy the gateway service from other provider.then next step is setup the gateway into your switch.that's it.after that you can build your own logic.

Comment: Yes you need to pay for gateway provider